# Is there a correct way to signal an annotation parser to ignore an annotation inside of a docblock?

Tags: php, annotations, phpdoc

Say I have a docblock comment that is parsed by, for example's sake, phpDocumentor and any annotation parser (let's say Doctrine common).

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Blah <blah@example.com>
 * Class to handle the generation of lorem ipsum text for our templates
 * To declare as a service in the DIC, __uncomment__ the following annotation
 * @DIC\Service("textgenerator.loremipsum")
 */
 class LipsumGenerator implements TextGeneratorInterface { }
```

Now, I don't want the `@DIC\Service` annotation to get parsed by default unless a user wants it parsed...obviously I could do any number things to prevent it: store it in a manual page instead of inline, put it in a non-docblock comment, etc. 

Is there a correct and relatively standard way to signal an annotation parser, **inline**, to ignore an annotation inside of a docblock?

Answer (score 0):

Try the --ignore-tags arg -- http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#using.command-line.ignore-tags

If you want to make a "permanent list" of such annotations to be ignored, your best bet is a custom config file that you always use when running phpDocumentor.  You can build a growing list of annotation tags to be ignored by all phpDocumentor runs that use the config file.

http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#using.config-files

Comment: I must not be seeing what your need is.  You want these annotations to not appear as generic "custom" tags in your generated documentation?  Or is there some other docblock use case that you are referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to annotations as used by Doctrine Common and other annotation parsing libraries.

Comment: Yes, I got that part ;-) , it's the annotations you're concerned about.  It's what / where you want them ignored that I must not be understanding.  I thought you meant "When I run phpDocumentor, I want those annotations ignored, rather than them showing up in my generated docs as if they were actual doc tags".

Hmmm, "any annotation parser (let's say Doctrine common)"... is that something used during the PHP *runtime* of the file?

Comment: Ah, then we are now outside the scope of my reckoning ;-)