# using PHP field annotations as flags

Tags: php, annotations

I have an DB management class
I want to simplify insert/update tasks for classes by automating it.
The class fields has the same name as the DB table columns.
I'm listing them using reflection functions and iterating through them for creating SQL string .

I want to ignore some fields and change some others (standardized changes)
How can I flag fields for my iterator to ignore them or run a change function on them?
I thought of PHP annotations (Like Doctrine) like this:

```
class test{
   public $field1;
   public $field2;
   /**
      @DB IGNORE
   **/
   public $field3;
   /**
      @DB IGNORE
   **/
   public $field4;
   public $field5;
   /**
      @DB CHANGE IMPLODE ,
   **/
   public $field6;
   public $field7;
}
```

**But how can I read/parse these annotations?

Any better idea?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742564/how-to-find-annotations-in-a-php5-object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745961/is-there-a-correct-way-to-signal-an-annotation-parser-to-ignore-an-annotation-in